# Recovering the contacts, SMS and call log from SD card

Tags: contacts, data-recovery

I am using an Micromax A57 running Android 2.3.5. Since there was a problem in the launcher, I reset the phone to factory settings, taking my SD card out before doing so. Since the phone's internal memory is very small, all the contacts, call log and SMS are saved on the SD card.

While doing the factory reset, my assumption was that I could restore this information from the SD card afterwards. However, when I re-inserted the SD card, my phone could not get any of my contact, SMS or call log information. I searched the Internet for the past 2 days and tried several applications to get it back but all in vain. My questions are:

First of all, would it be possible to get the SMS, contact and call log back from SD card (as I reset mobile alone taking SD card out)?

If possible, how to restore SMS, contact and call log?

Phone is rooted and I am sure the data lies somewhere in the phone as bits and bytes. Experts advise please.

Comment: How did you save the contacts &c. on the SD card in the first place? They're usually only stored on the internal storage.

Comment: I added the contacts in phone...but internal memory was just 150 MB effective in my phone and it was maintained on the same line...so my assumption was contacts also being pushed to SD card. were I wrong? And same applies for sms and call log also?

Comment: Unless you've done something special to move or export them to the SD card, they would have been on the internal storage, which means your factory reset deleted them.

Comment: Your assumption was incorrect. Contacts, SMS and Call logs are indeed stored on the internal memory of the device. Unless you synced your contacts to your Google account, backed up SMS and call logs, they are now lost after a factory reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption that Contacts, SMS and Call Logs are automatically saved to the SD Card was incorrect. They are indeed stored on the internal memory of the device. `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/` is the most likely storage location. That can change though, depending on Android OS version, manufacturer/carrier modifications, or even 3rd-party apps that you use in place of built-in Contacts/Phone/Messaging apps.

Unless you synced your contacts to your Google account, backed up SMS and call logs, they are now lost after a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrieve your contacts as google may have backed it up. 
Just add your google account to the phone and when sync is enabled the contacts will be back. 
But SMS and Call Logs may not restored.

Also from now on use any app to backup contacts, SMS, call logs etc. 
You can use [Super Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts) from Play Store.