# Recovering deleted call logs in Android 5.1.1 - to root or not to root?

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, data-recovery, call-history

I accidentally deleted my call logs/histories and badly need them now. I would like to recover the call logs and tried few softwares. Most of them were not successful in recovering the deleted call logs. Some are asking permission for `rooting` or `superuser` access.

- Is rooting a right thing to do for recovering my call logs? Will it affect my android phone in any unexpected ways?
- Are there any other ways or softwares where I could recover my deleted call logs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SMS and call logs are not backed up by google. So unless you have a backup its unlikely you can recover it. You should have used Super Backup from playstore to backup your call logs/SMS etc. [Related](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/66750/27149)

Comment: So the recovery apps that ask for superuser/root permission to recover call logs are scam? From what you say there is no way for me at all to get back the old deleted call history.

Comment: Does the app listed in playstore? Could you provide the app link(s).? I can only find this [android-pc recovery tool](http://www.recovery-android.com/recover-deleted-call-history-from-android.html) but i haven't used it myself. You can give it a try or have you already tried it?. And regarding rooting risks question see [Are there any risks to rooting a device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/164/are-there-any-risks-to-rooting-a-device)

Comment: Worst case scenario, if none of the apps work without rooting and if you dont want to root your device you can still call your service provider for your call log information.